# How to apply the Feynman-Kac formula?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I've been learning about [Feynman-Kac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) recently and I understand the underlying ideas. I am stuck however in actually computing explicit solutions for specific problems.

For example, suppose I have the following terminal value problem:

$$F_t + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2F_{xx}=1$$

$$F(x,T) = \ln(x)^4,~x>0$$

How would I compute $F(x,t)$ in closed form, given the closed form of the right hand side $(ln(x))^4$ using Feynman-Kac?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Maybe state the Faynman-Kac formula and see how it relates to your example first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the form of your equation, we can consider the SDE
\begin{align*}
dX_t = \sigma X_t dW_t, 
\end{align*}
where $W$  is a standard Brownian motion under the measure $Q$. Since, for $0 \leq t \leq T$,
\begin{align*}
X_T = X_t \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 (T-t) + \sigma \int_t^T dW_s \right),
\end{align*}
based on Feynman–Kac formula, the solution is given by
\begin{align*}
F(t, x) &= E^Q\left(\int_t^T ds + (\ln X_T)^4 \mid X_t = x\right)\\
&=(T-t) + E^Q\left[\left(\ln x  -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 (T-t) + \sigma \int_t^T dW_s\right)^4\right].
\end{align*}
The remaining is now simple and is omitted.

Comment: The computation of the expectation is simple, but may be tedious.

Comment: @SriramNagaraj if you're happy with the answer, then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

There is a little flaw in this equation:
\begin{align*}
F(t, x) &= E^Q\left(\int_t^T ds + (\ln X_T)^4 \mid X_t = x\right)\\
&=(T-t) + E^Q\left[\left(\ln x  -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 (T-t) + \sigma \int_t^T dW_s\right)^4\right].
\end{align*}

The correct one should be:
\begin{align*}
F(t, x) &= E^Q\left( - \int_t^T ds + (\ln X_T)^4 \mid X_t = x\right)\\
&=-(T-t) + E^Q\left[\left(\ln x  -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 (T-t) + \sigma \int_t^T dW_s\right)^4\right].
\end{align*}